# list videos in horizontal line not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a wordpress plugin for listing youtube channel videos. I'm using 'university' responsive theme and having bootstrap.

The youtube thumbnails are listed horizontally. But after integration to my theme it having some problems

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I don't think you can have a `<div>` as a direct child of a `<ul>`. That could be causing unexpected behavior. See ["permitted contents" at w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html). W3C HTML5 validator says "Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context."

Comment: The plugin having this structure. In their demos its working fine. I think some of the bootstrap css may affected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success by removing the `<pre>` tags that are wrapping the contents of `<article class="single-page-content">`.

Remember that `<pre>` tags respect white space, so all the white space between your `<li>` elements is being displayed. The whitespace is throwing off the alignment of floated `<li>` elements.

Here's a demonstration:

```css
.group:before,.group:after {content: "";display: table;}
.group:after {clear: both;}
.group {zoom: 1;}
div {
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <p>With &lt;pre&gt;</p>
  <pre>
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </pre>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <p>Without &lt;pre&gt;</p>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <p>With &lt;pre&gt; but no whitespace</p>
  <pre><ul><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li></ul></pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your code I found that adding this fixed the layout problem and the images lined up correctly.

```
ul.ytchagallery .ytc-row {
     display: inline-block
}
```

With that said I don't suggest using that plugin, they seem to use a lot of code which bloats your website and makes it a lot harder to debug. Also they use the `!important` tag which could cause problems with other CSS code in your website.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like nearly every definition in the ["Youtube Channel Gallery" stylesheet](http://54.84.11.219/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/youtube-channel-gallery/styles.css?ver=4.0.1) has `!important`.

Comment: I've tried this code. But still having the problem :(